# Azure B2C AD regarding anonymous users

Tags: crm, azure-ad-b2c, user-data, idp, anonymous-users

I have a quick Question regarding Azure B2C AD. Lets say I've decided to use Azure B2C AD As the identity Provider for a Web shop page.

Having the B2C AD for managing registered members/consumers/customers is all fine and dandy but, what about when a company (in this case a Web shop page) offers unregistered customer booking or buying. Or even just consumer/customer target  marketing against "anonymous" users.

Sure, I could user cookie information targeting IP-adressers and such. But what if even the cookie information is not reliable?

Suppose the described scenario above is not how Azure B2C AD is supposed to be used.

I've looked into Azure B2C AD, and some examples of CRM systems. But going of the premises of centralizing once Consumer-records (call them users or whatever - that is both registered and unregistered users), am i on the right track here?

Is there any good case studies on for example "combo-based" solution examples or anything like that?

I'm not asking for any direct solutions to this. Just trying to get an understanding/grip of explained scenario above.

Thanks // John

Comment: Digging into this for a while. No luck yet. Did you be able to find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure If I understand your question correctly, but according to my understanding: You want to login a user who is actually anonymous and doesn't have the email id and password.

Ans: You can use Client credentials grant with Azure AD B2C for the same. The anonymous user would not be required to enter the credentials. You can follow the link below for more info.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

**You can let me know if I am understanding your question correctly.**

Thanks